# Calling DRF api within another view in django 2.2

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I have an api view as:

```
class part_detail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = parts.objects.all()
    serializer_class = parts_serializer
```

I want to pass this as context in a detail view. Currently I am doing it as

```
def part_detail(request, id):
    context = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/bon/part_detail/'+id+'/?format=json').json()
    return render(request, 'frontend/part_detail.html',context)
```

But this will obliviously not work in production. How can I correctly call in apiview directly.

Comment: Are you trying to communicate between two separate applications?  If it is the *same* application then you should generate the response in `part_detail()` using the Django ORM, and avoid a network call.

Comment: Yes, they are the same application. And, yes I can do it that way, and yes, i know it would be efficient that way but still want to know if we can call the data using only api views

Comment: To get your code to work in different environments, you would encode the base URL as a field in your [settings file](https://djangostars.com/blog/configuring-django-settings-best-practices/#header4).  Then reference the setting in code, and your call will work correctly in the appropriate environment.